# File Cannot be accessed by the system in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, master-page

Hi when I was trying to copy the master page in SharePoint 2013 I am getting this error can anyone help me how to fix this issue I am copying master page through `admin account` but still shows this error.

[image]